# Control does not support transparent background colors

Tags: winforms, reportviewer, reportviewer2008, dotnetbar

I have `reportViewer` control. When i place it on regular `Windows forms` form report looks fine and background of it is white. That's good. Nevertheless i use `Dotnetbar` 3rd party `metro form` and when i placed `reportviewer` on it report background is very gray when running application. I tried to set `BackColor` property of `reportviewer` to tra`n`sparent but it says:

```
Control does not support transparent background colors.
```

My question is there any way to set `reportviewer` `backcolor` to `transparent` to get "normall" white background color?

Comment: What if you set the BackCoor to `Color.White` instead? The default BackColor should be `255, 236, 233, 216`. So, light gray-ish.

Comment: You should really be asking [DevComponents](http://www.devcomponents.com/support.aspx) why the ReportViewer background is not rendering properly on their form.  Is the problem only with the ReportViewer or is it any standard control with a white background color?  Have you tried setting the BackColor property of the report body to White in the RDLC designer (the default is "No Color"; i.e. transparent)?